# What is the default URL for Software Update on OS X 10.5.x?

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, leopard

I am fixing my mother-in-law's computer, and when I ran software update I found that the computer was looking to https://storeserver.local:8088/indes.sucatalog to get it's updates...   Clearly she has brought this machine to the Apple Store for some help at some point.

What is the correct URL for OS X 10.5 to get updates directly from Apple?

I know how to set the URl using:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL "_insert_correct_url_here"
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Bill

Answer (score 3):

The link below will take you to a page for multiple 10.5 combo  updates

http://support.apple.com/downloads/#os%2010.5%20combo%20updates

the link below is for 10.5.8 combo update

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL866

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what the proper URL is, but I did find that if I enter

```
defaults delete com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL
```

it deletes the bad entry by the Apple Store folks and allows me to get an enormous list of updates that need to be done.

I will still pursue the correct URL, and whomever answers that will get the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the catalog should have reset it to the default apple software update server.

But it should be swscan.apple.com if memory serves me.